# Showing the record progress using a round progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am developing a new Android application, In my application, i have audio record functionality of 3 sec. I want to show a round progress bar to show the progress of recording. The recording automatically stop after 3 sec. This is my code, Please help me to add the progress bar.

```
 private void mStartRecordingAudio() {
        try {
            TemporaryModelCache.stopMediaPlayer();
            TemporaryModelCache.getAsyncInstance().cancel(true);
            TemporaryModelCache.clearAsyncInstance();
            mAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            mAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            String file_name = mFileToSaveAudio + "recording.3gp";
            mAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(file_name);
            mAudioRecorder.prepare();
            mAudioRecorder.start();
            mImageViewRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_button_recording);
            circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mImagePlayOurs.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_button_play_ours_disabled);
            mButtonPlayRecordedAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_yours_disabled);
            mViewRecord.setEnabled(false);
            mViewPlayYours.setEnabled(false);
            mViewPlayOurs.setEnabled(false);

        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
            Log.e("error", ise.toString());
            // make something ...
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("error", ioe.toString());
            // make something
        }
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            mAudioRecorder.stop();
                            mAudioRecorder.reset();
                            mAudioRecorder.release();
                        } catch (RuntimeException stopException) {
                            //handle cleanup here
                        }
                        circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mWowWordActionSounds.mPlayAudioButtonClick();
                        mIsAudioRecorded = true;
                        mButtonPlayRecordedAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_button_yours_png);
                        mImagePlayOurs.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_playours);
                        mImageViewRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_record);
                        mViewPlayYours.setEnabled(true);
                        mViewPlayOurs.setEnabled(true);
                        mViewRecord.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the progress bar anywhere in the code

You should be using circularProgressBar.setProgress(circularProgressBar.getProgress()+1000); inside run().

But in my opinion, you should be using a Countdown Timer class instead of scheduling with Timer.schedule().

A simple example of CountDownTimer that will do a task inside onTick() after every 1 second and call onFinish() after 3 second

You can place the code for setProgress inside onTick().

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
  }.start();
```

Read more at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Comment: okay...but how can i set the progress means based on which value?

Comment: You said that your recording stops automatically after 3 seconds. So update the progress as time. What I mean by this is  - if 1 second has passed, update progress bar by 33%, 2 second 66% and when 3 second have passed, update it 100%.  To calculate the percentage use : milliSecondsUntillFinish value provided in onTick()